# What is a viable way of finding the minimum swaps to sort numbers in pyramid?

Tags: algorithm, data-structure, tree, sorting

I have made a game that consists of a pyramid of hexagons with numbers from 00 to 99 randomly positioned in groups of 6, 10 or 15 elements. Now, I'm working to create an auto-solver but for the last 2 weeks, I have got nothing really worth produced, and would like your help.
My objective is to determine the minimum swaps need to turn the left pyramid into the right pyramid:

[image]

Obviously, there's a catch: every cell can be exchanged only with it's neighbors cells, as below:

[image]

I've tried a lot of approaches with binary heap, BST and others, but I can't seems to find a proper answer. What would be the best algorithm choice to determine the minimum swaps needed to sort this hive?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Marcelo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very nice example of problem suited for [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). 
I will not go into details how to implement A* here as it has been done better before and this very easy to find, however this is how I would apply A* for your problem: 
As you can see, there is only a limited number of states that you can "move" to using single swap (14 for this case if I am not mistaken), you can think of them as a nodes in the (pathfinding)graph searched by A*. Naturally, you can only move to adjacent nodes and the distance from start node is the number of swaps made to reach "current" node. 
 What you also need for A* is function estimating the distance to goal state. Choosing good one is the key to speed of the algorithm, however pretty much any decent one will lead to the solution. I suggest using the sum of distances to goal postion, e.g. "1" is 1 swap away from its place, similarly "3" is two swaps away, all summing up to `distance = 8` for the state in your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot - will try to pursuit this approach. My goal for this special presentation is to get 6 movements (which is what I get by doing the swaps myself), I'll try to adapt an A* to it.